# Dynamic name in json key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to make a JSON dynamically but when I do something like this:

```
var jsonVar = {
    "section": {}
}

var elementsStoragePrefix = "_app_", 
    elementName = elementsStoragePrefix + "some_name";

$.extend(jsonVar .section, { elementName: "<option>This is a text</option>"});
```

I got the key as elementName and not _app_some_name

```
jsonVar.section =>
    Object
        elementName: "<option>This is a text</option>"
        __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When creating object literals, you don't need to quote the property names, so in your example `elementName` will be taken literally. Thankfully, you can use the square-bracket-syntax (or however you spell that):

```
var extendObject = {};
extendObject[elementName] = '<option>Foobar</option>';
$.extend(jsonVal.section, extendObject);
//or, to use brackets all the way:
$.extend(jsonVal['section'], extendObject);
```

That should fix things for you

Answer (score 4):

```
jsonVar.section[elementName] = "<option>This is a text</option>";
```